# number of possible arrays with certain conditions using dp

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

an array of increasing natural numbers between `1` and `n` is called beautiful if each number in the array is divisible by it's previous number. using dynamic programming, the question is to find the number of beautiful arrays with size `k` with the given time complexity:

1. `O(n*k*root(n))`
2. `O(n*k*log(n))`

what I could think of for the first one is that the number of divisors of a number can be found with `O(root(n))` time complexity. I want to design a recursive algorithm that calculates the number of possible arrays for each `i < k` but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be broken into two parts:

1. Find the divisor DAG (nodes 1…*n*, arcs *a* → *b* iff *a* divides
   *b*). Trial division will do this in Θ(*n* √*n*); enumerating
   multiples, in Θ(*n* log *n*). The graph has Θ(*n* log *n*) arcs.
2. Count the number of paths of length *k* in a DAG. This is a basic
   Θ((*m* + *n*) *k*)-time dynamic program. There is one path of length
   0 from each node. The number of paths of length ℓ from each node is
   the sum of the number of paths of length ℓ−1 from its successors.

Comment: what is m and could you please explain more about the dp part?

Comment: @mattdanny m is the number of arcs, which puts the total time at Theta(n k log n). The idea is that, to count paths of length ell, you have to break them down by first node and length from 0 to ell.